# VS Code Autocomplete Doesn't show after using it

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

it's a simple problem that has been bothering me for a long time, when I use autocomplete, the text I write after it becomes highlighted and suggestions don't show up anymore, does anyone know how to disable it?

[image: example]

it goes back to normal after pressing ESC

[Video Example](https://youtu.be/Qpeo47165_s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution is to go to VS Code Settings and disable following setting:

```json
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false // enables suggestions
```

[image]